# Nagios default value outside of timeperiod

Tags: nagios

I have a service that is being monitored during normal business hours but, occasionally, the service will go Critical at the last minute. This Critical status will carry on through non-business hours.

Is there a setting to change the value outside of this timeperiod? Or does anyone have scripts that I can throw into cron to mark certain services as OK when outside of their timeperiod?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

In **timeperiods.cfg**, define your custom time.

And use those defined timeperiods in service template (in check_period&notification_period)